# How do I set up Internet connection sharing in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, 3g, ics

This used to work, then it stopped.

Internet connection sharing host pc XP on an ethernet lan with client XP and client windows7.

Need step-by-step instructions for
host pc 
client xp
client windows 7

Not that it matters, but the host pc is accessing the internet via 3g usb modem.

Answer (score 3):

Step by step instructions:

`1.` Go to `Control Panel` > `Network Connections` (In classic view).

You should have two connections, one is your network card, the other your 3G modem.

At this point, you can run the Network Setup Wizard by choosing `Set up a home of small office network`. Internet Gateway is an option here:

[image]

If you want to proceed manually without the wizard:

`2.` Right click the connection that provides the internet connection and go to "Properties"

[image]

`3.` Click the Advanced tab and tick `Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection`.

[image]

`4.` ... Profit? ... You may need a restart, but it should now work!

If you are having problems, it is possible your 3G stick uses a third party (crippled) driver/dialler program. In this case, all I can suggest is to uninstall it and manually install the generic (Huawei (Most likely)) driver, and adding it as a modem, effectively bypassing the dialler program. You may need to do a search for your providers codes/dialling numbers.